# tf.get_variable() takes at least 1 argument (3 given)

Tags: tensorflow

Lets say, shape = (2, 3) and epsilon is a small constant. I ran two statements but got error with second one:

```
out = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape, -epsilon, epsilon))
```

No error for this one.

```
out = tf.get_variable(shape=shape, dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.random_uniform(shape, -epsilon, epsilon))
```

error:     out = tf.get_variable(shape=shape, dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.random_uniform(shape, -epsilon, epsilon))
TypeError: get_variable() takes at least 1 argument (3 given)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable), you must at least specify the `name` argument. So

```
out = tf.get_variable(name="myvar", shape=shape, dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.random_uniform(shape, -epsilon, epsilon))
```

should work.